# Web services can not return complete json

Tags: c#, json, ajax

I am developing an ASP.NET web application using web services and Ajax.
In web service, I have a method where I get data in Arabic, Urdu from the database and convert it into JSON But at the client-side, I didn't get the complete JSON format data which through an error in jquery of "JSON Parse".

For English my code work correctly, it only throws an error whenever there is some Arabic, Urdu data.

IN database I have the table named as "dd_diaryDetail"

What I have tried:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true, MessageName = "Gad")]
public void ThereIgetData(string forprocess, string filtervalue)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    object dta = null;
    using (DD_db db = new DD_db())
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var filval = filtervalue.Split(':');
        string cmd = "SELECT * FROM dd_diaryDetail WHERE (tcs_id = @tcsid) AND (dd_date = @dt)";
        dta = db.Database.SqlQuery<diarydetailview>(cmd, new SqlParameter("@tcsid", filval[0]),new SqlParameter("@dt", filval[1])).ToList();
        if (dta != null)
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
            var res_data = js.Serialize(dta);
            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", res_data.Length.ToString());
            Context.Response.Write(res_data);
            Context.Response.Flush();
        }
        db.Database.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The result I get an incomplete JSON array

```
[{"dd_id":8,"tcs_id":8,"dd_date":"02-03-2020","CW_unitno":"44","CW_title":"ajdsaj","CW_pageno":"۳۳","CW_qno":"۸۸","CW_activity":"طگطگشدش","HW_unitno":"۷۷","HW_title":"چفچفچف","HW_pageno":"۷۷","HW_qno":"۹۹","HW_activity":"شفچففچففچفچ","Tst_unitno":"۵۵۵","Tst_title":"چفچفشش","Tst_pageno":"۴۴","Tst_qno":"۳۳","Tst_activity":"رچرچ
```

Comment: remove this line   >>  Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", res_data.Length.ToString());